# Customizable Data Input Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to recreate the set of controls shown in the attached image, taken from a winform project.

There will always be at least 8 rows, sometimes there will be 16.

What is best wpf control or controls to achieve this?

The columns are: -

1 - a label
2 - a checkbox
3 and 4 - datatimepickers
5 - a group of checkboxes
6 - a combobox
7 - a datetimepicker
8 - a combobox

Comment: The image appears to have been lost.

Comment: Must have been blocked by the security system. Apologies. I will send the image when I get home.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is dynamically create a row of controls for each of a number of objects.

In which case, your view model should have an ObservableCollection of those objects (which probably need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/INotifyPropertyChanged_2.aspx)). Your view should have an [ItemsControl](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) with its ItemsSource bound to that collection. The ItemsControl will contain a datatemplate that contains the 8 controls you list.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Your information sent me down the path I was after.